# Character Array Pointers and Casts from Integers (Memory Address)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-address

Okay, currently I am writing a kernel for the sake of my resume. While writing my memory management unit I have hit a brick wall.

```
int address = (int)malloc(sizeof(Test))
consoleWriteString("Variable Address:\n");
consoleWriteInteger(address);

char* f = (void*)address;

consoleWriteString("\nVariable Address:\n");
consoleWriteInteger((int)&f); // Should print off the same as above
```

Logically the output should be the same for both. Somewhere somthing has gone wrong though. as my output is the following.

```
Variable Address: 47167
Variable Address: 1065908
```

After a long period of testing and debugging I finally gave in and decided to ask stack overflow. Also if you spot any syntax errors ignore them. By the way this is all in C, and all functions are custom, including malloc, but I have determined that the error does not lie in that functon, or any other for a fact. I believe this is just me being stupid about pointers and casting but don't laugh at me when it was somthing super simple that I missed.

Thanks yall

Comment: Assigning pointers to integers and silencing your yelling compiler with casts? That's the road to disaster. Why not use `void *address` or `char *address`? If the reason is there's no `consoleWritePointer` then write one!

Comment: Thanks for the information, for a consoleWritePointer how would I proceed to write that? Just convert it to an address in hex and then print from there?

Comment: If you already have a Standard C conforming printf, use the `%p` specifier for pointers; if not, cast the pointer value to an unsigned integral value and print that (or use a union, stick in a ptr and read an unsigned value).

Comment: Actually I don't have a standard printf yet, in order to do that I need string manipulation which requires memory allocation. This whole problem originated from me trying to test my malloc, finding that it worked, but when I attempted to create a char array at an address that it would be messed up.Thanks for telling me how to print it though, every thing helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&f` is the address of `f`, not the address contained in it! `f` is on the stack. Its value (the address you first printed) is pointing to the allocated memory.

Think of it this way: You allocate room in memory for some stuff. This memory region has an address. You put the address in a pointer (`f`), so that it *points to* that region. But `f` itself needs to be somewhere in memory in order to hold the value of that address. In this case, `f` is on the stack, and `&f` gets the address of `f` (the container of the original address), not the address that `f` contains.

As an aside, be very careful casting addresses to `int` (and back!), since `int` might not be large enough to hold an address (e.g. on x86-64, depending on your compiler). I believe the correct type to use when you want to use an address as an integer is `uintptr_t` in `stdint.h`.

Comment: Good advice about the size of address vs the size of `int`!

Comment: Thank you for the helpful and quick response, also for the warning about using ints to hold address values.

Answer (score 1):

The **value** of f (which happens to be a pointer) is the same as `address` (which is also a pointer, but of a different type) - this is what you do in the line

```
char* f = (void*)address;
```

But then you print the **address** of f:

```
consoleWriteInteger((int)&f);
```

And that is not the same thing as the **value** of f... change that line to

```
consoleWriteInteger((int)f);
```

and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

the first print out is an int, although malloc returns an address, The second is an address casted to an int. do `f` instead `&` gets you the address of a value while `*` dereferences a pointer getting you the value of what is being pointed to.

Comment: OP isn't asking for the value of what is being pointed to, but the address. Thus "use `*f`" is the wrong advice. "Use `f` rather than `&f`" is the right advice, as explained in the other two answers.

Comment: @Floris i changed it but I'm not sure why it matters since everything about the OP is incorrect, if he doesn't understand how malloc works not sure why he's writing a kernel

Comment: We all get a momentary "brain fart" some times - and we'll stare at something that is obvious to anyone else. It matters that we try to make sure that answers on SO are (to the best of our ability) correct, even if the questions make us scratch our heads.

Comment: I understand how malloc works because the one In that code is the one that I wrote. Also 48 hours without sleep has a tendency to screw me over. It is finals week at my university...